# Filtering the result of a JSON.parse response in Ruby (and the JSON gem)

Tags: ruby, json

In a little app I'm building, I'm using the the twitter_oauth gem ([source of the methods I'm using](http://github.com/moomerman/twitter_oauth/blob/master/lib/twitter_oauth/direct_messages.rb)), which incidentally means I'm dealing with the JSON ruby gem.

I'm using the messages method, whose source is as follows:

```
def messages(page=1)
      oauth_response = access_token.get("/direct_messages.json?page=#{page}")
      JSON.parse(oauth_response.body)
end
```

It parses the JSON produced by Twitter, using the JSON.parse method. Now, what I want to do is filter the response, so as to show only the messages sent by a certain user. In other words, I want to be able to get an accounts message's on a per user basis.

I went through the JSON gem docs, but couldn't find an easy way to do this. I normally don't work with JSON (I prefer XML), but since the Twitter_oauth gem relies on it, I'm forced to learn it (unless I change the gem's source code or overwrite it - not of my preference).

Does any one know a pragmatic way of sorting JSON in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have to work with JSON at all? `JSON.parse` gives you back deserialized structures (Ruby arrays and hashes), so all you have to do (I presume, you haven't pasted sample JSON output here) is to do `select` on whatever output `JSON.parse` (or, in your case, `messages`) method returns.

Comment: Yes, I figured I could filter the response, but didn't know how the response was structured. I'm working on it now, thank you.